# Facebook User ID is always 0

Tags: php, facebook

I've recently changed webhosts. Since then, I keep getting 0 for the Facebook User ID:

```
<?php 
$app_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/the_rsg/";
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($canvas_page);
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='".$auth_url."'</script>");
}else{
    $pageContent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$data["user_id"]);
    $parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
    $user_id = $parsedJson->id;
    $user_name = $parsedJson->name;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $user_id;
}
?>
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: did u change the basic settings for your Facebook app properly?

Comment: Yup I did, changed the canvas URL

Comment: Does the rest of the data return correctly?

Comment: So lost with this since this actually worked a couple of days ago & now it doesn't.
Well actually it only half worked I suppose, it did return 0 for the UserID at times but very rarely & now it just does it every time.

Answer (score 1):

On checking the error log:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/xxxxx) [function.file-get-contents]:
>
> failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/jay/public_html/index.php on line 20

The problem is in the php.ini file.

The solution is to enable `allow_url_fopen`.